# Mixed Model Ordinal Regression - number of questions don't affect power?

Tags: r, mixed-model, statistical-power, ordinal-data

I'm doing a study where two groups of individuals will answer a number of questions. Let's call the amount of individuals in each group Ni and the amount of questions Nq. No individual will be in  both groups, but the same questions will be used in both groups. The answers are graded on an ordinal scale from 1 to 5. To perform a *power analysis*, I ran a *simulation in R*, but I had some *unexpected results* which I hope you can help me interpret!

I have two fake datasets, group A and group B. Each contains 1000 individuals and their score for 1000 questions (the same questions in both groups), where there is some difference in mean score between the different individuals and a difference in mean score between the different questions. This represents the individuals having different skill levels and the questions different difficulty. The scores are normally distributed and the mean difference in scores is around 0.33 between the two groups.

I will use individual number and question number as random effects. The dependent variable is the score and the fixed independent variable is the group (A or B).

I ran a simulation with different Nq and Ni. For each set of values I drew random data from the two datasets (the same questions in both groups) and I fitted the model with `clmm()` in R. I checked how big proportion p was < 0.05 to get the power.

My expectation was that increasing the number of questions AND increasing the number of individuals in each group would BOTH give me higher power. But the result seems to indicate that the number of questions doesn't matter much. The table below shows the estimated power for different Ni and Nq:

| Questions.N | Ni20 | Ni40 | Ni60 | Ni80 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 120 | 38.1 | 72.8 | 91.2 | 98.2 |
| 90 | 46.9 | 72.3 | 83.8 | 94.2 |
| 60 | 47.0 | 74.7 | 81.9 | 94.5 |
| 40 | 41.0 | 64.6 | 86.9 | 93.1 |

Here is the output of a single run of the clmm function, if it helps:

```r
Cumulative Link Mixed Model fitted with the Laplace approximation

formula: Score ~ Group + (1 | Participant) + (1 | question_number)
data:    combined_data

 link  threshold nobs logLik   AIC     niter     max.grad cond.H 
 logit flexible  3200 -3314.33 6642.66 438(3624) 4.84e-04 3.1e+02

Random effects:
 Groups          Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Participant     (Intercept) 3.136    1.771   
 question_number (Intercept) 3.220    1.795   
Number of groups:  Participant 80,  question_number 40 

Coefficients:
       Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
GroupB  -0.6036     0.4023    -1.5    0.134

Threshold coefficients:
    Estimate Std. Error z value
1|2  -5.0220     0.4170 -12.044
2|3  -1.9507     0.4049  -4.818
3|4   1.0193     0.4036   2.525
4|5   3.8919     0.4110   9.469
```

**So my question is**: Shouldn't the amount of questions matter as much, or almost as much, as the amount of participants in the test for the power of the analysis? Or is what I see the expected result (why in that case)? Is it likely that something is wrong in my calculation? I could post my entire code here as well and more details about how I created the datasets, but it would be a long post. Please, tell me if you want it!

---

**EDIT: Additions requested by comments:**

| Comment | Addition |
| --- | --- |
| What is the hypothesis? | The hypothesis in my study will be that there is a difference in the performance between the two groups. To be specific this doesn't refer to a difference in mean scores (though that's what I have created in my dataset for the simulation), since the scale is ordinal and the mean may not be a valid measure. Instead I hope to detect a difference in the log odds of picking a higher score in one group compared to the other. I'm trying to find the sample size needed to detect a significant difference at least corresponding to the difference in my fake datasets. |

Comment: This makes sense to me. If you have multilevel data (for example, observations within individuals) and your primary predictor of interest varies at the individual level, then the limiting factor is not the number of observations w/in individuals, but the number of individuals.

Comment: What is the hypothesis?

Comment: @ErikRuzek Thank you! You may be absolutely right! To me it still seems a bit strange, tough. In a real scenario - e.g. testing a group of policemen vs firefighters on trivia -  What if we used only a few quesitons and two happened to be about putting out fires? Also, comparing a single individual with that of another (for example using Man Whitney U:s test), more questions would surely give higher power. Why not when comparing a group with another? I'm not saying you are wrong, only that I still don't understand it intuitivly...

Comment: Please ad that information as an edit to the post, and not only as a comment. We want posts to be self-contained, comments on this site are ephemeral, can be deleted, and are often seen only by a few!